# Magento Sales Order number adding "-1" on the end after editing

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

We're always upgrading an order when an item is out of stock so we go to order > edit > delete invoice > enter new item >submit order.

It will be updated and invoice it but after clicking the submit order it was redirected to a attached screen and creates a duplicate order which adds a "-1" at the end of the order number. (i.e. 200005270-1)

How can this happen?

Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't natively support Order edits. It actually just cancels the first order and creates a new ones (then appends -1 to the original increment ID).

Comment: yes your right, but when we edit some orders, it does not adds a -1 to the increment ID. It just replaced the order item. Thanks!